# Wordpress wp_enqueue_script Not inclode js file

Tags: wordpress, themes, add-action

I'm developing a theme and trying to get `wp_enqueue_script` to work.

But it is not included, except that the CSS file is working.

I have this function:

```php
function KYT_admin_scripts($dir)
{
    if('toplevel_page_KYT' != $dir){

    }

    wp_register_style('KYT-admin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/admin.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('KYT-admin');

    wp_register_script('KYT-admin-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/admin.css', array('jQuery'), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('KYT-admin-js');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'KYT_admin_scripts');
```

Comment: You're including a CSS file as JS. -> `'/js/admin.css'`

Comment: But it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

it's working.
the problem was in:

array('jQuery')

it's should be a Small Latter: array('jquery')